# Uniform convergence of a specific sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**

Studying for my finals currently and one of the my book's questions goes as follows, prove what you can about the uniform convergence of the following series by Theorem II (Weierstrass M-test). State specifically the range of values of $x$ about which you make an assertion.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n+1}x^n$$

**My Work**

I know that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$$ is uniformly convergent on $-r\le x \le r$ if $0<r<1$. It's also clear to me that $\frac{n}{n+1} \le1$, so it's bounded.

> Can I therefore conclude that this is uniformly convergent on $$0 < x < 1$$ 
>   by the weierstrass M-test?
>   Is there a wider interval this is uniformly convergent on?

Comment: Surely not wider: if $|x|\gt 1$, the terms don't go to $0$.

Comment: And even if $|x|=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start was great. But what you can conclude from your observations is that the series converges uniformly (absolutely) (and actually [normally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence)) on $[-r,r]$ for every $r<1$, since
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\;\sup_{[-r,r]}\;\frac{n}{n+1}|x|^n=\sum_{n\geq 1}\;\frac{n}{n+1}r^n\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}<+\infty.
$$

Now for every $|x|\geq 1$, the general term does not tend to $0$, so the series diverges. So these intervals above are afortiori the best you can do.

So the series converges absolutely on $(-1,1)$. And it converges normally, hence uniformly on every $[-r,r]$ with $0\leq r<1$.

**Attention:** the series does not converge uniformly on $(0,1)$ as you said. Otherwise, the general term would converge uniformly to $0$. But
$$
\sup_{(0,1)}\;\frac{n}{n+1}|x|^n=\frac{n}{n+1}\longrightarrow 1\neq 0.
$$
A very similar argument shows that there is no uniform convergence on $(-1,0)$ either. So the intervals $[-r,r]$ with $r<1$ are really the best you can do for uniform convergence.